# How to avoid nested loops in python? Need to optimize code

Tags: python-3.x, optimization, nested-loops

> Putting code for reference. Values of first loop are using in second
> loop to filter the dataframe and so on. Need to optimise it. Im using
> python 3.7. Can’t think of how to use itertools here

```
for i in dataframe1['col'].unique():
    d1={}
    d1['title']=i
    d1['val']=dataframe1[dataframe1['col']==i]['col2']
    
    for j  in dataframe2['col'].unique():
        d2={}
        d2['title']=j
        d2['val']=dataframe2[dataframe2['col1']==i]['val']
        
        for k in dataframe3['col'].unique():
            d3={}
            d3['title']=k
            d3['val']=dataframe3[(dataframe3['col1']==i) & (dataframe3['col2']==j)]['val']
```

Comment: Welcome to [Stack Overflow.](https://stackoverflow.com/ "Stack Overflow")! It is very difficult to answer your question without seeing both the data and the code that you have written that produces your problem. Please read about how to ask a good question and try to post a [Minimal Reproducible Example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example "Minimal Reproducible Example") so we can better help you.

Comment: I Have provided the code. Can you pls respond on the basis of that

Comment: Pls feel free to ask me anything in particular

Comment: It is very difficult to answer your question without seeing the data!  Please include a sample of the data which is causing your issue, and the expected result you desire to be produced, as suggested in the MRE.

Comment: Careful that you know what `j` you are using as you redefine it.

Comment: You repeatedly calculate and filter the same results (unique items) on every nested loop.

Comment: @jonsg corrected that